# Is everything in nature a source of heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, kinetic-theory, heat-conduction

A source of heat is something from which heat is originated or obtained,
whereas heat is the energy transferred due to temperature difference so heat is relative as the temperature difference is. Thus,
everything in-universe is a source of heat for someting.

Comment: How is a bottle of liquid nitrogen a source of heat? Sure, it *could* be if it came in contact with something even colder - is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, This is for what I was asking.

Answer (score 2):

Heat is a somewhat technical tearm in thermodynamics/statistical physics, which means energy transfer on a microscopic level (as opposed to *work* which is energy transfer on macroscopic level). Temperature is a quantity characterizing thermodynamic equilibrium. So, speaking of *heat* makes sense only when we discuss energy exchange between systems in tehrmodynamic equilibrium. There are plenty of situations in the Universe which do not fall into this model situation, and applying term *heat* to them is meaningless.

Comment: What are those plenty of situations which doesn't falls into this model situation?